# R using Merge: "id variables not found in data:"

Tags: r

My data has a structure as follows:

```
<ID> <Gender> <Age> <St> <Ep1> <Ep2> <Ep3> <Ep...>
```

Meaning, the number of `Ep#` columns is bound to change and to be quite large. Now what I'm trying to achieve, is to see if there is a difference in their distribution based on gender. Each `Ep#` column at this point, simply contains the amount of observations - to simplify the data frame - per `Ep`. In order to do so, I looked at the `reshape2` package, and before melting the data, I extracted the `<Ep#>` column names, onto a variable named `columnNames`.

```
maleFrame <- melt((columnNames),(simpleFrame[simpleFrame$`Gender (Binary)` == 1,])[, -2], 
                  id.vars="columnNames", measure.vars="Idade", "`Gender (Binary)`")
```

Unfortunately this yields an error:

```
Error: id variables not found in data: columnNames
```

Upon reading some threads, it seems the problem is the `columnNames` must be character or integer types, and as of right now, they seem to be levels. However, when I try to convert them to integer using `as.numeric(as.character(columnNames))` or other methods, they all return a vector of 1's, when in reality, they should parse the true value, such as `90010001`. In fact, using `head(columnNames)` yields (I cut the result as its quite large):

```
> V9      V11      V13      V15      V17      V19      V21      V23      V25      V27      V29      V31      V33      V35      V37      V39
1 90009901 90009902 90009911 90009999 90010001 90010002 90010003 90010004 90010005 90010006 90010007 90010008 90019901 90020003 90020004 90020005
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try using `gather` from the `tidyr` package to do the reshaping - something like `df2 <- gather(df,key=ExpNo,value=Value,-c(1:4))` would convert all the `Ep` columns to long format.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, worked like a charm!